# prometheus node exporter sockstat

Tags: linux, monitoring, tcp, unix-sockets

I'm looking for the meaning of the node_sockstat_TCP_mem_* metrics.
The output of the node exporter describes them as follows:

```
# HELP node_sockstat_TCP_mem Number of TCP sockets in state mem.
# TYPE node_sockstat_TCP_mem gauge
node_sockstat_TCP_mem 6
# HELP node_sockstat_TCP_mem_bytes Number of TCP sockets in state mem_bytes.
# TYPE node_sockstat_TCP_mem_bytes
```

The states I know for a socket are like "ESTABLISHED", "LISTEN", "CLOSE_WAIT",... What is this "mem" state ?

Comment: I just saw  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33855/kernel-socket-structure-and-tcp-diag?rq=1  in the "Related" section once I submitted my question. It wasn't mentioned when I was making the question.